# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade process, upgraded to 16.04 without do-release-upgrade

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, apt, upgrade

I had to upgrade an Ubuntu server running 14.04 to 16.04 to get it into compliance.  Is it normal that after running 'apt-get upgrade' - that lsb_release -a shows 16.04?  Why is this?  I have yet to run do-release-upgrade.

Comment: It *is* normal for the distribution name/version to be updated, but I don't know what files or packages are responsible. I'd guess `ubuntu-minimal`.

Comment: The way to tell for sure is to check your /etc/apt/sources.list. If you do not understand that file, then post it's contents on your question.